# <include/> set to default XML values

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Hi I have a layout which has `<include/>` in it. I can access this include and change the visibility of some views in it or modify the edittext text.

So what I want is to create a method so that when I press a button the layout inside the `<include/>` would turn into its original XML state hiding what was hidden in XML and showing what was shown and to return the edittext to their default values from the original XML layout file.

Note that I am not using any fragments or changing the `setContentView` in my application.

Thank You So Much.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve that seems to be to start a new instance of the current activity and to `finish` the existing one.

Comment: @Henry The current activity is the main activity of the program, is their any way else than starting a new instance of that activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution for this problem what I did is to copy the OnCreate code to another method thus it is callable then what I will do is `setContentView`to be the layout that I want to turn it back to its default case then calling the method that contains the OnCreate code to return all the ids then using the include method I can show the layout inside another layout.